# Will all the images in a html slideshow be downloaded at once?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I need to make a slideshow of images in my AngularJS app. I'll be storing the images in a remote server.

I'm planning to use a simple image slideshow using css something like this. I have not implemented angularjs in this. I'll be using `ng-repeat` to create the image in the view.

```
<div class="mySlideShow">
  <img class="mySlide" src="http://www.example.com/img1.jpg">
  <img class="mySlide" src="http://www.example.com/img2.jpg">
  <img class="mySlide" src="http://www.example.com/img3.jpg">
  <div class="w3-center w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
    <div onclick="loadImg(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div onclick="loadImg(1)">&#10095;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'll be having more than 50 images in the server.

My question is will all the images be loaded at once or they will be loaded only when they come to view?

If they will be loaded at once how can I make it to load only when they come into view? I do not want the app to load all images at once. If possible I want to implement it using javascript or angularjs not jquery.

Comment: Short answer is yes. An ng-repeat will put all of those image tags into the HTML source and the browser will make a network request for each image when it loads that page.

Comment: Here's an example of how you might implement a lazy loading slider http://derekknox.com/articles/lazy-loading-carousel-images-in-angular-bootstrap/